# SBT - how to make an InputTask depend on one task and doFinally another

Tags: sbt

We're putting together an SBT Build for some automated Android UI tests. The aim is to start an Appium server, start the Android emulator, run the tests, then close everything down. We've got this working for the 'test' SBT command:

```
(test in Test) <<= 
  (stopVirtual, (test in Test), saveProcessVirtualKey)
  {
    (stop, test, saveProcessVirtualKey) => test.dependsOn(saveProcessVirtualKey).doFinally(stop)
  }
```

We are running into problems when trying to perform the same with the 'testOnly' command, which should take in a string argument to specify a specific test to run. What we've got so far is:

```
(testOnly in Test) <<=
  (stopVirtual, (testOnly in Test), saveProcessVirtualKey)
  {
    (stop, test, saveProcessVirtualKey) => test.dependsOn(saveProcessVirtualKey).doFinally(stop)
  }
```

Really we need to make an InputTask depend on saveProcessVirtualKey and doFinally stopVirtual. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sbt has built-in [test setup and cleanup](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing.html#Setup+and+Cleanup).

> Specify setup and cleanup actions using `Tests.Setup` and `Tests.Cleanup`. These accept either a function of type `() => Unit` or a function of type `ClassLoader => Unit`. The variant that accepts a ClassLoader is passed the class loader that is (or was) used for running the tests. It provides access to the test classes as well as the test framework classes.

```scala
Test / testOptions += Tests.Setup( () => println("Setup") )
Test / testOptions += Tests.Cleanup( () => println("Cleanup") )
```

Would that work?

I am posting this for the second time because my previous answer was deleted by a moderator.